# Sum of falling factorials

Tags: summation

How do I find the sum with given $\alpha$:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\alpha^{\underline{k}}}{k}=?$$
There's a tip in the task to find $\Delta \alpha^{\underline{n}}=\alpha^{\underline{n+1}}-\alpha^{\underline{n}}$. So we get
$$\Delta \alpha^{\underline{n}}=\alpha^{\underline{n}}(\alpha-n-1)$$
I can't see any connection between sum and this equation.

Comment: What is the significance of the underline under the index $k$ in: $\alpha^{\underline{k}}$?